# SQL query to search for row that has lowest difference to a search number if you have doubles on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my situation, I have a table with these columns:

1. FormID
2. AbilityGenID
3. Ability1ID
4. Ability2ID
5. HiddenID

To search for certain records I have a query to search for all rows where the `AbilityGenID <= 6`.

```
SELECT TOP (2000) 
    [FormID],
    [AbilityGenID], [Ability1ID], [Ability2ID],
    [HiddenID]
FROM 
    [PokéDex].[dbo].[tblPokemonAbilities]
WHERE 
    AbilityGenID <= 6;
```

This still returns duplicate rows on the `FormID`, which is actually normal since the `FormID` and `AbilityGenID` combination is unique.

| FormID | AbilityGenID | Ability1ID | Ability2ID | HiddenID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 3 | 61 | NULL | NULL |
| 15 | 3 | 68 | NULL | 97 |
| 16 | 4 | 51 | 77 | 145 |
| 17 | 4 | 51 | 77 | 145 |
| 18 | 4 | 51 | 77 | 145 |
| 16 | 3 | 51 | NULL | 145 |
| 17 | 3 | 51 | NULL | 145 |
| 18 | 3 | 51 | NULL | 145 |
| 19 | 3 | 50 | 62 | 55 |
| 21 | 3 | 50 | 62 | 55 |

The problem I have is, that I want to search for all records that not only have the `AbilityGenID` equal or lower to the search number (in this case 6). But in case if I have double `FormID` records has the lowest difference between `AbilityGenID` to the search number.

How do I do this?

Edit: This is an example result.

| FormID | AbilityGenID | Ability1ID | Ability2ID | HiddenID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 3 | 61 | NULL | NULL |
| 15 | 3 | 68 | NULL | 97 |
| 16 | 4 | 51 | 77 | 145 |
| 17 | 4 | 51 | 77 | 145 |
| 18 | 4 | 51 | 77 | 145 |
| 19 | 3 | 50 | 62 | 55 |
| 21 | 3 | 50 | 62 | 55 |

Comment: You should include the result you want, because it's a bit unclear on what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to rank the resulting rows per form and only keep the best ranked, i.e. the one with the highest AbilityGenID.

```
SELECT
    [FormID], [AbilityGenID], [Ability1ID], [Ability2ID], [HiddenID]
FROM
(
  SELECT
      [FormID], [AbilityGenID], [Ability1ID], [Ability2ID], [HiddenID],
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [FormID] ORDER BY [AbilityGenID] DESC) AS rnk
  FROM 
      [PokéDex].[dbo].[tblPokemonAbilities]
  WHERE 
      AbilityGenID <= 6
) ranked
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. This did the trick.I will need to figure out a way later to translate this to in LINQ. But that is not rhe question here. Thank you this will help me a lot further with my project.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT [FormID],
    [AbilityGenID], [Ability1ID], [Ability2ID],[HiddenID]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FormID ORDER BY ABS(AbilityGenID - 6)) AS rn
    FROM [PokéDex].[dbo].[tblPokemonAbilities]
    WHERE AbilityGenID <= 6
) AS Ranked
WHERE rn = 1
AND FormID IN (
    SELECT FormID
    FROM (
        SELECT FormID, MIN(ABS(AbilityGenID - 6)) AS min_diff
        FROM [PokéDex].[dbo].[tblPokemonAbilities]
        WHERE AbilityGenID <= 6
        GROUP BY FormID
    ) AS MinDiffs
    WHERE ABS(AbilityGenID - 6) = min_diff
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).